# Re apply javascript after pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I have an issue with my masonry code.

It works fine on pageload, but the items that are inside the masonry can be filtered, I am doing this using ajax and I'm replacing the entire div with elements to show the filtered items.

After this happens, the masonry code is not applied again and it falls apart.

How can I make sure the masonry stays applied even when content changes after pageload?

In my footer I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.gridlist').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.masonryitem',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
      });
  });
</script>
```

Then in my custom.js I have the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   /* Ajax code voor aanbiedingen */
  $("#branche").on('change', function() {
    var option = $('#branche > option').filter(':selected');

    if(option.val() == 'default'){
      $.post("includes/ledenall.php", {
        filter: option.val()
      }, function(result){
        $("#content1").html(result);

      });
    }else{
      $.post("includes/leden.php?option=" + option.val(), {
        filter: option.val()
      }, function(result){
        $("#content1").html(result);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Which returns my php file, but this time without the masonry being applied.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reapplying your isotope library after changing the DOM:

```
/* Ajax code voor aanbiedingen */
$("#branche").on('change', function() {
  var option = $('#branche > option').filter(':selected');

  if(option.val() == 'default'){
    $.post("includes/ledenall.php", {
      filter: option.val()
    }, function(result){
      $("#content1").html(result);
      $('.gridlist').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.masonryitem',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
      });
    });
  }else{
    $.post("includes/leden.php?option=" + option.val(), {
      filter: option.val()
    }, function(result){
      $("#content1").html(result);
      $('.gridlist').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.masonryitem',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I don't know if `.gridlist` is totally replaced in your updated DOM. If not, you may need to somehow "remove" the old isotope instance, but something like this is what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty simple, should've thought about that. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Add your code to a function

```
function func() {
    $('.gridlist').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.masonryitem',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
    });
}
```

Then you can call the function and apply your isotope at any point you want